# Python3 import module from subfolder2 in subfolder1

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following file structure

```
MainDirectory
    | Subfolder1
        | script1.py
    | Subfolder2
        | __init__.py
        | script2.py
```

I want to import the the module `script2.py` in the `script1.py`. 
With `Python2.7` I was able to do it like this:

The `__init__.py` contains the code:

```
 from script2 import ClassA
```

File `script1.py` contains the following import structure:

```
 sys.path.insert(0, "../")
 from SubFolder2 import ClassA
```

But when I run the same in Python3 then I get an

```
 ImportError: No module named 'script2'
```

What would I have to change to get it to work with Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '/'.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).split('/')[0:-1])+'/Subfolder2')
import script2
```

Comment: Yep it does, but it seems really complicated compared to the Python2.7 version!?

Comment: @wasp256 I am not sure, but I suppose this is that way in Python3 in order to discourage you from using it and encourage you to look for a way to restructure the code so that you don't need it anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that this resource is in a parent directory...

```
from ..SubFolder2 import script2
```

Comment: Then I receive the following error: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`